# Cannot execute ssh-ed osascript properly inside of shell script

Tags: vpn, shell, shell-script, applescript, osascript

I have created a ip-down script in my etc/ppp/ directory. Essentially I am trying to kill certain programs/servers when the VPN disconnects, then display a notification on another computer via ssh. I have setup ssh keys and the following command works fine in terminal, but not inside the script:

```
ssh {userName}@{address} 'osascript -e "display notification \"The VPN has disconnected.\" with title \"Server\" sound name \"Pop\""'
```

Everything else in the script works. My full script below:

```
#!/bin/sh

killall someApp1
killall someApp2
killall someApp3
killall someApp4
ssh {userName}@{address} 'osascript -e "display notification \"The VPN has disconnected.\" with title \"Server\" sound name \"Pop\""'
vpn-connect &
```

Side Note:
I was trying to block all torrent traffic on en0 (ethernet on this device) with pf.conf but when I would block it wouldn't let me connect to my vpn. I was not sure how to allow it. I was able to allow ssh, https, screen sharing, etc. Any information on that would be cool too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an answer, but a work around.

Context: I have an older Macbook which I use as a headless Plex sever. I would like to keep it connected to VPN pretty much always. I would also like notifications when it connects and disconnects.

I ended up creating a event handling app. Then I used Apple Remote Events to call it and pass in arguments. After the arguments are passed and the event handler runs I tell the application to quit. This keeps it from just idling in the background. Lastly, I hid my notification from the dock by editing the plist. The reason I created a handler app instead of just using Finder to display the notification is because I wanted to have a customized icon for my notification.

Code for the Notification Helper (Event Handler):

```
on run
    idle
end run

on idle argv
    try
        eHandler(item 1 of argv, item 2 of argv, item 3 of argv)
    end try
end idle

on eHandler(message, title, soundName)
    set theMessage to message as string
    set theTitle to title as string
    set theSoundName to the soundName as string
    display notification theMessage with title theTitle sound name theSoundName
end eHandler
```

ip-down shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

# kill applications 
killall someApp1  
killall someApp2
killall someApp3     
killall someApp4

# Open Notification Helper
osascript <<EOF
set remoteMachine to "eppc://{userName}:{password}@{address}"
tell application "Finder" of machine remoteMachine
    open ("/Applications/Notification Helper.app" as POSIX file)
end tell
EOF

# Sends Notification Helper arguments
osascript <<EOF
tell application "Notification Helper" of machine "eppc://{userName}:{password}@{address}"
    TestHandler("The VPN has been disconnected.", "Media Server", "Pop")
    quit
end tell
EOF

# Calls applescript which reconnects my VPN. 
# The & Stops script from waiting to end
vpn-connect &
```

For those who don't know an ip-down script goes into you /etc/ppp/ directory and runs when the VPN is disconnected. You can also make an ip-up script, which runs when you connect to your VPN. My ip-up just turns on all my services and then sends me a notification letting me know the VPN is backup.

Comments, suggestions are appreciated. Still interested in understand why this would work, as it I have another script which notifies me when x happens from another program via ssh. Also still very interested in pf.conf. The syntax for it is very confusing to me.